# Chart using SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, xslt-list-view-web-part

I'm a newbie trying to use create a pie chart from a SharePoint list. The name of the list Mgmt_list and I'd like to display the count of the "Responsible Dept".  "Responsible Dept" is currently a string. This is what I have cobbled together from another post.

```
<div id="piechart" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       var tempArray = [];
       var chartObj = [['status', 'Number']];

AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mgmt_list')/Items?$select=Responsible Dept", function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, value) {
        if (0 > tempArray.indexOf(value["Responsible Dept "])) {
            tempArray.push(value["Responsible Dept"]);
            chartObj.push([value["Responsible Dept"], 1])
        } else {
            chartObj[tempArray.indexOf(value["Responsible Dept"]) + 1][1] += 1;
        }
    });
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartObj);
        var options = {
            title: 'Certification Report Status',
            is3D: 'true'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
});
});
function AjaxCall(url, success) {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: success,
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        alert('Something Went Wrong');
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create the column with the name is "Responsible Dept", the internal name of this field will be "Responsible_x0020_Dept".

Modify the code as below to make it works.

```
<div id="piechart" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tempArray = [];
    var chartObj = [['status', 'Number']];

    AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mgmt_list')/Items?$select=Responsible_x0020_Dept", function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, value) {
            if (0 > tempArray.indexOf(value["Responsible_x0020_Dept"])) {
                tempArray.push(value["Responsible_x0020_Dept"]);
                chartObj.push([value["Responsible_x0020_Dept"], 1])
            } else {
                chartObj[tempArray.indexOf(value["Responsible_x0020_Dept"]) + 1][1] += 1;
            }
        });
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartObj);
            var options = {
                title: 'Certification Report Status',
                is3D: 'true'
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    });
});
function AjaxCall(url, success) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: success,
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            alert('Something Went Wrong');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Do I need to make adjustments to the code if I would create another chart off a choice field?

Comment: Yes, you need adjust the code if you use other field.

Comment: What changes would I need to make for the different fields types?